# Which module do I need when I got error info "Can't locate getopts.pl in @INC..."

Tags: macos, perl, cpan, getopts, cpanm

I run this command in my macOS

```
$ perl ~/Desktop/blif2cnf.pl
```

and got this error info:

```
Can't locate getopts.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /Users/Frank/Desktop/blif2cnf.pl line 10.
```

In my linux 16.04, such problem can be solved by following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233386)

Is there a module like `libperl4-corelibs-perl` in macOS?

I know CPAN, but I don't know which module should I install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Perl4::CoreLibs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl4::CoreLibs). In general the Debian package `libthis-that-perl` corresponds to a module named `This::That`, although it's up to you to figure out the capitalization :)

Comment: Are there any document sites where I can search for the module that I need?

Comment: @sirius, you can find the details in the answer below, but the quick version is:   [http://search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org)  or   [https://metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how the package manager works with macOS, but a platform-independent way of installing the `getopts` package.

To answer the question you put as a comment to the answer from @hobbs, the way I searche for a module I need is either through the site that @hobbs linked, https://metacpan.org, or, alternatively, [http://search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/). It was at the second that I found what I needed.

Searching for `getopts.pl` gave a link to "Perl4::CoreLibs". In the upper-right-hand corner, there was a link that said Perl4-CoreLibs-0.003.tar.gz (though it looks like there is a 0.004 now). I right-clicked and selected "copy link address", which gave me

`http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/Z/ZE/ZEFRAM/Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004.tar.gz`

Whatever your link is, you'll need to untar it and find all the `*.pl` files in the `lib` directory into a directory, and either

1) Link to them from the command line, e.g.

```
perl -I /path/to/where/you/untarred/lib ~/Desktop/blif2cnf.pl
```

or

2) Add them to your `PERLLIB` environment variable.

I think that more details will be helpful.

---

#### Detailed Instructions

Figure out a directory where you want to download your `*.pl` files. I used `$HOME/new_perl_stuff`

```
cd ~

mkdir new_perl_stuff

cd new_perl_stuff
```

Now, get the tarball

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/Z/ZE/ZEFRAM/Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004.tar.gz
```

untar it, go into the directory, and make sure `lib` is there

```
$ tar -xzf Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004.tar.gz

$ cd Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004

$ ls
```

You should see `lib` in the list.

It's possible to add your newly downloaded `lib` directory (in my case, `$HOME/new_perl_stuff/Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004/lib`) to the `perl` search path, but this just makes me worry about another directory that I might delete at some time. I made a new folder in the `/usr/lib` directory. I decided to name the new directory `libperl4-corelibs-perl`, since that seemed standard. First, I checked to make sure that there wasn't already a directory with that name.

```
$ stat /usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl
stat: cannot stat '/usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl': No such file or directory
```

Then I made the directory.

```
mkdir /usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl
```

The next step was copying all the `*.pl` files into this directory. I hope to explain this next command later. I ran it this way to make sure all of the files I needed were there. From my `$HOME/new_perl_stuff/Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004` directory, I ran the following command, which I plan to come back and explain.

```
find ./lib -type f -name "*.pl" -print0 | xargs -I'{}' -0 \
bash -c 'new_dir=/usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl/; chmod +x {}; \
echo "Moving {}"; mv {} ${new_dir} && echo -e "success\n" || \
echo -e "failure\n"' | tee moving_day.log
```

Run that one if you want to see that everything got copied successfully. A shorter command that does everything necessary is:

```
find ./lib -type f -name "*.pl" -print0 | xargs -I'{}' -0 \
bash -c 'new_dir=/usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl/; chmod +x {}; \
mv {} ${new_dir}'
```

It's not a bad idea to run

```
ls -lah /usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl
```

to check that the `*.pl` files are there.

You can now run

```
perl -I /usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl ~/Desktop/blif2cnf.pl
```

but there's an easier way.

Finally, I made it so that this directory will become part of the `perl` search path every time I use a terminal by adding the following line to my `~/.bashrc`
This command adds the path to the `PERLLIB` environment variable. Different flavors of Linux have different syntax for adding to environment variables, **make sure to find out what yours is!**

```
export PERLLIB="/usr/bin/libperl4-corelibs-perl:$PERLLIB"
```

The commands I ran for this were

```
$ echo -e "\n\n## allow Perl to use the files in Perl4::CoreLibs" >> $HOME/.bashrc

$ echo -e "export PERLLIB=\"/usr/lib/libperl4_corelibs_perl:$PERLLIB\"" >> $HOME/.bashrc

$ source .bashrc
```

Now, you can simply run

```
perl ~/Desktop/blif2cnf.pl
```

---

**Note**: It's probably a good idea to go back and remove unwanted extras:

```
rm -rf $HOME/new_perl_stuff
```