# sclite (SCTK) `make check` faliure, C++/perl/Cygwin, Safe to use Perl4 stuff?

Tags: c++, perl, makefile, kaldi, perl4

I am currently trying to install NIST's `sclite`, which is part of SCTK 2.4.0 ([github](https://github.com/chinshr/sctk) or [newer version](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools)). I am attempting the install on `Cygwin` in `bash`. The installation is done using `make`.

I have gotten past the `make configure` and `make all` parts of the installation. This didn't come without some effort (See the SO posts on the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50278663/6505499) (`file not recognized`) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50243691/6505499) (template/scoping) problems). When I get to the `make check` part of the install, a lot of the checks/tests pass, but then I get the following error.

```
Testing acomp.pl
   No tests defined for acomp.pl
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src/acomp'
(cd def_art; make check)
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src/def_art'
Testing def_art.pl
   def_art.pl passed without tests
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src/def_art'
(cd hubscr; make check)
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src/hubscr'
Testing hubscr.pl
./RunTests.pl
   Running test 'test1-sastt', operation 'test', options '-G -f rttm -F rttm -a', directory 'test1-sastt.test'
      Executing command
Error: unable to get the version for program def_art.pl with the command 'def_art.pl' at ../hubscr.pl line 419.
Error: Execution failed at ./RunTests.pl line 30.
make[2]: *** [makefile:20: check] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src/hubscr'
make[1]: *** [makefile:68: checkFast] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src'
make: *** [makefile:52: check] Error 2
```

I've done some research (described below), and I've been able to get past this problem. However, this involved including some outdated `perl` modules (Perl4).

My first question was how to fix this error or how to skip that part of the test. I've been able to fix the error, and if people think that it's safe, I'll put it as an answer. Note that there is one more problem with `make check` after this problem is fixed, but I mention how to get past that at the end.

**I'm wondering if using the old Perl (`Perl4::CoreLibs`) is safe and/or good programming practice. Would it be better to change the source code to use Perl5 stuff?**

**Is there a better way altogether?**

<s>One thing I want to be sure of is that there are no critical tests further down the `make check` line which might fail.</s>

---

#### System Details

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 CAP-D-ENG-INT3 2.10.0(0.325/5/3) 2018-02-02 15:16 x86_64 Cygwin
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) ...
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.4.0 ...
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.4.0 ...
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin ...
$ systeminfo | sed -n 's/^OS\ *//p'
Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
Configuration:          Member Workstation
Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

---

#### My Attempts/Research

From the output above, we have `def_art.pl` passing the check because there are no checks - "`def_art.pl passed without tests`". However, the next thing checked, `hubscr.pl`, failed. The error comes from `def_art.pl`.

The obvious thing to do seemed to be to run `def_art.pl`, which I did.

```
$ ./src/def_art/def_art.pl
Can't locate getopts.pl in @INC 
(@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26 /usr/lib/perl5/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/5.26) 
at ./src/def_art/def_art.pl line 40.
```

So it seems to me that this is a deprecated `perl` file (or module, or whatever).

I dug a little further and found [this discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/kaldi/discussion/1355348/thread/f8794e3e/?limit=25) on a `kaldi` discussion from 2014. (`kaldi` is a speech-recognition toolkit that uses the SCTK scoring system). There are 3 sections of the discussion that I think are especially relevant, which I will link ([first](https://sourceforge.net/p/kaldi/discussion/1355348/thread/f8794e3e/#d9d0), [second](https://sourceforge.net/p/kaldi/discussion/1355348/thread/f8794e3e/#d9d0/61d0/1f50), [third](https://sourceforge.net/p/kaldi/discussion/1355348/thread/f8794e3e/#d9d0/61d0/1f50/5c4b)). I'll insert parts here:

> `def_art.pl` is looking for `getopts.pl` which I coudn't find on my machine!
>
> ... [T]hese are legacy packages that are no longer supported in recent versions
>   of Perl 5. I don't think we should accept a dependency on them. They have
>   been deprecated since the beginning of Perl 5.
>   Instead of 'require "getopt.pl"', we should be doing
>   `use Getopt::Std`
>   (note: modern `perl` code should not call "`require`" for system packages).
>   There is a similar issue with "`flush.pl`" in the Perl scripts. I don't know
>   what the Perl 5 package name is.
>   ... There are several places where this occurs.

I finally found that both `getopts.pl` and `flush.pl` are available from [`Perl4::CoreLibs`](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Perl4-CoreLibs-0.003/lib/Perl4/CoreLibs.pm). The URL that I use for `wget` was referenced at this site. Apparently, in other `*NIX` distros, the package manager can be used, e.g.

```
apt-get install libperl4-corelibs-perl
```

or

```
yum install perl-Perl4-CoreLibs
```

but I could not find an install via `apt-cyg`. I was able to install them from a tarball, as described in the *What I'm Doing* section.

One again, I'll state my main question: **Is this safe/good programming practice? Is there a better solution?**

If there is a better solution (using Perl 5), it seems that [this link](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl4::CoreLibs) might lead the way to it.

---

Some other links that are possibly related: [link_{n}](https://pkgs.org/download/perl(flush.pl)) and [link{n+1}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4538767/6505499) about `flush.pl`, [link_{n+2}](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224716) & [link_{n+3}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47990911/6505499) about `getopts.pl` and `Perl4::CoreLibs`.

---

#### What I'm Doing

```
$ mkdir perl_added

$ cd perl_added

$ wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/Z/ZE/ZEFRAM/Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004.tar.gz

$ tar -xzf Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004.tar.gz  

$ cd Perl4-CoreLibs-0.004
```

Rather than adding this directory's `lib` subdirectory to the `PERLLIB` environment variable with a one-time command-line, environment-variable-addition thing, I did the following.

Make a new directory in the `/usr/lib` directory, move the files there

```
$ stat /usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl
stat: cannot stat '/usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl': No such file or directory
# Checked that the directory didn't already exist. It didn't exist.

$ mkdir /usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl

# Make each file executable, then move it into the new directory
# I'd like to come back and explain this.
$ find ./lib -type f -name "*.pl" -print0 | xargs -I'{}' -0 \
bash -c 'new_dir=/usr/lib/libperl4-corelibs-perl/; chmod +x {}; \
mv {} ${new_dir}'
```

Finally, I made it so that this directory will become part of the `perl` search path every time I use a terminal by adding the following line to my `~/.bashrc`
This command adds the path to the `PERLLIB` environment variable. Different flavors of Linux have different syntax for adding to environment variables, **make sure to find out what yours is!**

```
export PERLLIB="/usr/bin/libperl4-corelibs-perl:$PERLLIB"
```

The commands I ran for this were

```
$ echo -e "\n\n## Allow Perl to use the files in Perl4::CoreLibs" >> $HOME/.bashrc

$ echo -e "export PERLLIB=\"/usr/lib/libperl4_corelibs_perl:$PERLLIB\"" >> $HOME/.bashrc

$ source $HOME/.bashrc
```

(Thanks to @melpomene for noting that the current version is 0.004, not 0.003.)

After that, I went back to the base folder of the install and ran `make clean`, `make config`, `make all`, and `make check`.

That did get me farther in the `make check` but not by far.

**I'm wondering if using the old Perl (Perl4::CoreLibs) is safe and/or good programming practice. Would it be better to change the source code to use Perl5 stuff?**

P.S. After all this, you probably want to go back and delete the folder where you untarred everything. In my case:

```
rm -rf /path/to/where/I/started/perl_added
```

---

#### The Result/Next Steps

A bunch of tests that passed and then

```
(cd hubscr; make check)
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src/hubscr'
Testing hubscr.pl
./RunTests.pl
   Running test 'test1-sastt', operation 'test', options '-G -f rttm -F rttm -a', directory 'test1-sastt.test'
      Executing command
Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/{_recursive_/_recur_{ <-- HERE _sive_/_si_ve_}_}/ at ../../md-eval/md-eval.pl line 1099, <DATA> line 12.
Error: MDEVAL failed
      Command: md-eval.pl -nafcs -c 0.25 -o  -r sastt-case1.ref.rttm.filt -s sastt-case1.sys.rttm.filt -M sastt-case1.sys.rttm.filt.mdeval.spkrmap 1> sastt-case1.sys.rttm.filt.mdeval at ../hubscr.pl line 679.
Error: Execution failed at ./RunTests.pl line 30.
make[2]: *** [makefile:20: check] Error 255
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src/hubscr'
make[1]: *** [makefile:68: checkFast] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/David/programs/sctk2.4.0/sctk/src'
make: *** [makefile:52: check] Error 2
```

Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238539/automake-error-unescaped-left-brace-in-regex-is-deprecated) will be helpful. I will post a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50283077) for this issue or, if the solution is quick, I will add the solution on this post.

Comment: Why did you specifically get version 0.03 of Perl4::CoreLibs? The latest release is 0.04 (see e.g. https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl4::CoreLibs).

Comment: What exactly is your question now?

Comment: Thanks @melpomene. I just happened to find version 0.03 first on my Google search. Thanks!

Comment: @melpomene. Thanks for asking about my current question. I will edit the question (and take some un-necessary stuff out.) **Now, I want to know if using this Perl4 code is safe, or if I should try and edit some of the source code.**

Comment: There is a way that I think is easier. Basically, you install the `tools` part of [kaldi](http://kaldi-asr.org/). You can also install the `src` part and use it if you want (unless you're on Cygwin under Windows 7 as I am, in which case there are more problems.) If you just want the `sclite` stuff, copy `/path/to/kaldi/tools/sctk-2.4.10/*` to a place that's not inside the kaldi tree. I did `mkdir $HOME/sctk-2.4.10 && cp /path/to/kaldi/tools/sctk-2.4.10/* $HOME/sctk2.4.10/` . I'll probably elaborate later. Then you can `rm -rf /path/to/kaldi` .

Comment: Note that the fixes described here and in the other solutions to which I've linked ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283077/6505499), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50243691/6505499)) are also needed if one uses a more current version of `sclite` available at jaguar.ncsl.nist.gov/pub/sctk-2.4.10-20151007-1312Z.tar.bz2

Comment: That more-current-version link might change, so here's the hosting site: [https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A Better Way

(Actually, a couple of better ways. See my comment under the question for the `kaldi` solution.)

In talking with colleagues and friends, it seems that there isn't anything unsafe about the Perl4 stuff. I did find a better way to get them "installed", but I'll leave the notes in the question showing the "long way" with the tarball, `PERLPATH`, etc.

Check that you have `CPAN`

```
$ which cpan
```

If you see something starting with `which: no cpan in (...)`, you most likely don't have it. Try installing `perl`. For me, on Cygwin, I used

```
$ apt-cyg install perl
```

(Install `apt-cyg` if necessary, cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16869816/6505499) for instructions.)

You probably won't have to install Perl. You will likely see something like `/usr/bin/cpan` as the output of `which cpan`. If so, you're good. Enter `cpan` at the command prompt.

```
$ cpan
```

If it's your first time, it will ask a bunch of questions about the configuration. I just pressed "Enter" to accept the default each time, I finally got a prompt like this:

```
cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.18)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]>
```

There, I entered

```
cpan[1]> install Perl4::CoreLibs
```

The install will proceed. When it will have finished, you will be able to type `exit` and press "Enter", which will take you back to the `bash` command prompt.

```
cpan[2]> exit
Lockfile removed.

$
```

At this point, `make check` will still choke, but the install will complete successfully. If you want the `make check` to get all the way through, go to the "*Getting past `make check`*" section below. At this point, though, you can do the last two steps in the process.

```
$ make install
```

At this point I added the install path to my `PATH` variable. Hopefully, I'll be able to put in a link about that process. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14637979/6505499) is a one-time solution.

```
$ export PATH=/path/to/sctk/bin:$PATH
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/6505499) is a lasting solution.

Now, for the last step in the installation process:

```
$ make doc
```

After the `make doc`, I made sure that the `man` pages were available. I looked on my machine until I found the place where other `man` files went. (Sorry, I don't have a systematic way of doing it, I just looked in a lot of places.) For me, on Cygwin, the directory was `/usr/man/man1`

I went into the `doc` directory

```
cd doc
```

and copied all of the files into the directory I had found

```
cp -r ./* /usr/man/man1/
```

Note that there are also now `html` and `htm` files in the directory that also provide documentation.

---

#### Getting past `make check`

So, you really want to see it go through without errors. You need to change the following file: `src/hubscr/RunTests.pl`

Originally it has the following beginning, which I have used the `head` command to show.

```
$ head -n 15 src/hubscr/RunTests.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $operation = (defined($ARGV[0]) ? $ARGV[0] : "test");
sub runIt{
my ($op, $testId, $options, $glm, $hub, $lang, $ref, $systems) = @_;
my $baseDir = $testId.".base";
my $outDir = $testId.($op eq "setTests" ? ".base" : ".test");
print " Running test '$testId', operation '$op', options '$options', 
directory '$outDir'\n";
system ("mkdir -p $outDir");
system ("rm -fr $outDir/test* $outDir/lvc*");
### Copy files
foreach my $file($glm, $ref, split(/\s+/,$systems)){
    system("cp $file $outDir");
```

Change it so that, after the `print` command, you have new lines as follows. I again use the `head` command to show the beginning of the file

```
$ head -n 63 src/hubscr/RunTests.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
my $operation = (defined($ARGV[0]) ? $ARGV[0] : "test");

sub runIt{
    my ($op, $testId, $options, $glm, $hub, $lang, $ref, $systems) = @_;
    my $baseDir = $testId.".base";
    my $outDir = $testId.($op eq "setTests" ? ".base" : ".test");

    print "   Running test '$testId', operation '$op', options '$options', directory '$outDir'\n";

    ####DWB, 2018-05-21 Getting `make check` to work####
    if ( $testId eq "test1-sastt" &&
         $operation eq "test" &&
         $options eq "-G -f rttm -F rttm -a" &&
         $outDir eq "test1-sastt.test" ) # <problem 1>
    {
        print "\n";
        print "\n#### SKIPPING ####";
        print "\nJust kidding. That breaks the make.";
        print "\nIt said: \n\n";
        print "\nUnescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/{_recursive_/_recur_{ <-- HERE _sive_/_si_ve_}_}/ at ../../md-eval/md-eval.pl line 1099, <DATA> line 12.";
        print "\nrror: MDEVAL failed";
        print "\nCommand: md-eval.pl -nafcs -c 0.25 -o  -r sastt-case1.ref.rttm.filt -s sastt-case1.sys.rttm.filt -M sastt-case1.sys.rttm.filt.mdeval.spkrmap 1> sastt-case1.sys.rttm.filt.mdeval at ../hubscr.pl line 679.";
        print "\nError: Execution failed at ./RunTests.pl line 30.\n\n";
        print "\n"
        print "\nThat's a perl legacy problem, see:"
        print "\n[https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375505/291375][1]"
        print "\nI'm outta here.";
        print "\n   Sincerely, bballdave025";
        print "\n";
        print "\n";

        return;

    }#endof:  if (<problem 1>)

    if ( $testId eq "test2-sastt" &&
         $operation eq "test" &&
         $options eq "-G -f rttm -F rttm -a" &&
         $outDir eq "test2-sastt.test" ) # <problem 2>
    {
        print "\n";
        print "\n#### SKIPPING ####";
        print "\nJust kidding. That breaks the make.";
        print "\nIt said: \n\n";
        print "\nError: Test test2-sastt has failed.  Diff output is :";
        print "\ndiff -i -x CVS -x .DS_Store -x log -x '*lur' -I '[cC]reation[ _]date' -I md-eval -r test2-sastt.test/sastt-case2.sys.rttm.filt.alignments/segmentgroup-116.html test2-sastt.base/sastt-case2.sys.rttm.filt.alignments/segmentgroup-116.html";
        print "\n 45c45";
        print "\n < jg.drawStringRect(\"SUB48\",0, 47, scale*656, \"left\");";
        print "\n ---";
        print "\n####  and a whole bunch of other draw stuff! ####";
        print "\n1 at ./RunTests.pl line 61.\n\n";
        print "\n"
        print "\nThat looks like Java drawing code, and I don't"
        print "\neven want to mess with it!"
        print "\nI'm outta here.";
        print "\n   Sincerely, bballdave025";
        print "\n";
        print "\n";

        return;

    }#endof:  if (<problem 2>)

    system ("mkdir -p $outDir")
```

Now you should be able to get through. Try it:

```
make check
```